# Repeater SelectMethod - How to get the number of items returned?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a asp.net repeater's SelectMethod to return my objects. Is it possible to get the number of Items being returned?

I was originally using `<%#: Items.Count %>` but quickly realized that is not returning the correct number of objects returned.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="docResults" runat="server" 
     ItemType="ArchiveViewer.Models.Document" 
     SelectMethod="GetSearchResults" >
     <HeaderTemplate>
         <p class="result-info">
             Found <strong> <%#: Items.Count %> </strong> results.
         </p>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>                                  
        <div>
           Title: <%#:Item.Metadata.Title %>
        </div>  
        <div>
            Author: <%#:Item.Metadata.Author %>
         </div> 
     </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

EDIT: As requested: my GetSearchResults method...

```
[WebMethod]
public IEnumerable<Document> GetSearchResults(
          [QueryString("query")] string query, 
          [QueryString("type")] string queryType)
    {
        IEnumerable<Document> results = null;
        try
        {     
            ArchiveSearcher searcher = new ArchiveSearcher();
            results = searcher.SearchMetadata(query, queryType, 1, 20);

            if (results.Count() > 0)
            {
                // Display the first search result in the viewer
                Document firstResult = results.FirstOrDefault();
                hfCurrentDocId.Value = firstResult.DocumentId.ToString();
                hfImageDir.Value = firstResult.FolderPath;
                hfObjectData.Value = firstResult.JSONPath;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log the exception.
            ArchiveViewer.Logic.ExceptionUtility.LogException(ex, 
                "GetSearchResults in Search.aspx.cs");
        }          
        return results;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: what you are getting for `<%#: Items.Count %>` ?

Comment: 'Items' is list of script managers. I'm not sure why...

Comment: Show us `GetSearchResults`

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the count control with a label and an ID:

```
<HeaderTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="TotalCount" runat="server" />
```

After data binding, you can get the count of repeater items, grab the TotalCount label from the control.  Some people used an approach like:

```
Repeater1.Controls(0).FindControl("TotalCount")
```

To extract it, and set it after databind.  Remember the Repeater Items collection has the header in it, so you want to count the repeater items only.  To grab the count of items, do:

```
Repeater1.Items.Where(i => i.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
```

You have to include the item types you want to count,  mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.itemtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: So, I'm getting the Header when I do 'Items.Count'? How can I get the repeater items?

Comment: You have to omit the header,so using LINQ I think you can do `Repeater.Items.Where(i => i.ItemType == ListItemType.DataItem)` which are only the items within the item template.  If you use alternate template, there is a separate item type for that.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.itemtype(v=vs.110).aspx